# BGP session in cloud router does not accept advertised default routes

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have set up a VPN tunnel from my on prem datacenter to a Google Cloud project.

I have set up a BGP session on my on prem router, and on a Google Cloud router, that works, and they can see each other subnets and I can ping instances from each side.

The problem comes when I advertise a default route 0.0.0.0/0 from my on prem datacenter to my Cloud router. I have removed the 0.0.0.0/0 default route from my Google Cloud network already. So what this setup will do is route all egress traffic from Google Cloud instances to the on prem network. That default route is not accepted by Cloud router and not added to the routes table.

Can someone explain if cloud router has a filter against default route advertisements via BGP ?

Comment: Could you provide extra information, such as which region is your VPN&Router in? Which region is your instance in? Is the Cloud Router in regional or global mode? How is your on-prem router configured? What does `gcloud compute router get-status` and `describe` return?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Google filters route 0.0.0.0/0 from BGP. However, you can workaround this if you announce 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 via BGP.